# Find certain characters in cell with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a cell where a link can be pasted. For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

I want the cell next to it say "wrong" IF the text contains "**/**" or "**:**" or "**=**". It should say "Correct" is none of these 3 characters are found in the text.

```
For example:
test/
Would give "Wrong" because it contains at least 1 "/"

/test:
Would give "Wrong" because it contains at least 1 ":" and at least 1 "/"

test///////
Would give "Wrong" because it contains at least 1 "/"

test/:=
Would give "Wrong" because it contains at least 1 "/", at least 1 ":" and at least 1 "/"

test123{}+_)
Would give "Correct" because it does not contain any "/", ":" or "="
```

I tried to work with nested IF, but I couldn't get it to work. I kept getting errors when adding the third character to the formula.

Comment: Post your formula please

Comment: Thanks Robin. Mrig has already solved the problem. Thanks for reading my question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(":",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("=",A1))),"Wrong","Correct")
```

or prefereably this one

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"/",":","="},A1))),"Wrong","Correct")
```

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: https://scontent-amt2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/19702530_10155469840874817_951356275574787929_n.jpg?oh=a2e669b1094011eb370962dc4b4bc09b&oe=59D049E1

Comment: I have no idea how to add pictures, but the link above will lead to a screenshot of the result. Giving me "correct" on everything.

Comment: Correction, I made a typo while pasting the code. I fixed the error and its working fine now :D Thanks.